# How to implement Angular Template Driven Forms that contains a lot of Components?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

this questions is more about best practice and architecture.
I work on project that was writed on angular 2.
There are a lot of forms and all this forms are very Big. It is difficult to search something in that. And it's not easy to support that.

When a start to refactor some forms. I split this to list of components (and components are contains another components).

But built-in validation was broken. It was due to Angular isolation and angular awas cannot get errors list from components input elements.

All examples in internet is about reactive forms.
I know that it's better to use reactive forms but this is imposible to rewrite all code in one time. And it's not correct to merge both types of forms.

As a solution a make a class that implements ValueAcessor and Validator, and bind Model instead of Input variables.
Then inject all childs with NgModel
And subscribe to it theirs ngModel.valueChanges.

It seems like control that throws child errors to upper level.

And so the question: Is it correct to create such controls in "Angular philosophy"? So why nobody not implements such solution? (I try to find somethig like this but not found.)

May be there is a some best practice and more correct solutions?

Comment: Could you please provide your code snippet?

Comment: Check this:https://medium.com/@a.yurich.zuev/angular-nested-template-driven-form-4a3de2042475

Comment: This example is not fully correct. ViewProvider will broke isolation. What if it will be a list on <address\> elements? Then Json will has only one "address" field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ControlValueAccessor](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor) is the standard way to implements form component.

It works with both reactivs and template driven forms.

I've tried to handle this kind of component with `@Input` and it was a mess at the end. Components will only split the code but won't be independant.

Using `ControlValueAccessor`, you can create a component which only requires a model object. Then, any time you'll need the form component, you won't be stuck with only one type of form (reactiv or template driven) and most importantly, the child component won't drive the way the form has to be built.